# Pagefile usage fluctuating with zero paging I/O

Tags: memory, windows-8.1, paging

I fired up the Performance Monitor and noticed that the `% Usage` on the 4GB pagefile fluctuates between 4-10% while the computer is sitting "idle." (I calculate that to be approx. ~160-400MB.) Memory usage is sitting steady around 8GB.

The system has 64GB of RAM, and the pagefile resides on a 1TB SSD.

None of this is terribly confusing.

What is confusing is that *there is zero write I/O going to the pagefile even as the `% Usage` continues to fluctuate.*

In the last hour, `% Usage` has gone from a minimum of 4.1% to maximum of 9.7%, now sitting at 5.6%. Yet the total of `Page Writes/sec` as shown by Performance Monitor, as well as bytes written to pagefile.sys as reported by Resource Monitor, both remain at zero for the last hour (0 page writes, 0 bytes written.)

How is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Pages write/sec in perfmon and the write bytes/sec in Resource Monitor are not cumulative figures. They are instantaneous rates. Your system has obviously written something to the pagefile - just not at times when you happened to be watching the counters.